# Keep data from reaching below 0

Tags: php

Im working on a browser game where i need to handle energy. The user spends and gets energy but i have come across an issue that i have tried to fix, When a user has for example 20 Energy and he does something that spends 30 energy it's going through and ofcourse i understand because i am checking the value to not go below 0 like this

```
if ( 0 < $resultenergy[0]['energy'])
```

This means that unless the users energy is at 0 he can spend whatever he want. What would be a better way to check the data so it alerts when "trying" to go under 0 ?  I appreciate all help and if you have an idea of a different approach im all ears.

Comment: Check before you allow the *spend* `if (($energy-$item_energy) < 0) false` :/

Comment: A nice UI would hide/dim what the user couldn't afford, making it more clearer.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You are clearly mistaken; it's much more fun to relive the bad ol' days of MySpace game mechanics such as [Mafia Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_Wars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the calculation once.

```
$remaining_energy = $current_energy - $energy_cost;
```

Then check the result, and act accordingly.

```
if ($remaining_energy >= 0) {

    $current_energy = $remaining_energy;
    // do whatever required the energy
    // send the client a succes indicator
} else {
    // don't change current energy
    // send the client an error indicator
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i wanted. Sometimes you just dont see those clear things.

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract and then evaluate. e.g.

```
if ( 0 < $resultenergy[0]['energy'] - $energyCost) {
    $resultenergy[0]['energy'] = $resultenergy[0]['energy'] - $energyCost;
    return true
} else {
    return false;
}
```

$energyCost is the cost of whatever action they're trying to do.